# How to create a state store with HashMap as value in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I need to create a state store with String key HashMap as value. I tried the below two methods.

```java
// First method
StateStoreSupplier avgStoreNew = Stores.create("AvgsNew")
          .withKeys(Serdes.String())
          .withValues(HashMap.class)
          .persistent()
          .build();

// Second method
HashMap<String ,Double> h = new HashMap<String ,Double>();

StateStoreSupplier avgStore1 = Stores.create("Avgs")
          .withKeys(Serdes.String())
          .withValues(Serdes.serdeFrom(h.getClass()))
          .persistent()
          .build();
```

The code compiles fine without any error, but I get a runtime error

```
io.confluent.examples.streams.WordCountProcessorAPIException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown class for built-in serializer
```

Can someone suggest me what is the correct way to create a state store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a state store, you need to provide a *serializer* and *deserializer* class for the type you want to use. In Kafka Stream, there is a single abstraction called **Serde** that wraps serializer and deserializer in a single class.

If you use `.withValues(Class<K> keyClass)` it must hold that

> @param keyClass the class for the keys, which must be one of the types for which Kafka has built-in serdes

Because there is no built-in `Serdes` for `HashMap` you need to implement one first (maybe called `HashMapSerde`) and give this class to the method `.withValues(Serde<K> keySerde)`. Furhtermore, you must implement the actual serializer and deserializer for `HashMap`, too. If you know the generic types of your HashMap, you should specify them (what make the implementation of serializer and deserializer much simpler.

Something like this (just a sketch; generic types omitted):

```java
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

public class HashMapSerde implements Serde<HashMap> {

    void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        /* put your code here */
    }

    void close() {
        /* put your code here */
    }

    Serializer<HashMap> serializer() {
        return new Serializer<HashMap>() {
            public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
                /* put your code here */
            }

            public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
                /* put your code here */
            }

            public void close() {
                /* put your code here */
            }
        };
    }

    Deserializer<HashMap> deserializer() {
        return new Deserializer<HashMap>() {
            public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
                /* put your code here */
            }

            public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
                /* put your code here */
            }

            public void close() {
                /* put your code here */
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you want to see examples for how to implement (de)serializers and `Serde`, have a look into https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization and https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serdes.java

Comment: Thanks @matthias-j-sax. I will try this one.

Comment: @matthias : How can we define serde for Hashmap<?,?> ?

Comment: Implement `Serde` interface.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I checked out how the ListSerde is implemented, but it doesnt look very easy to implement. Why is there no default implementation like the ListSerde in the kafka streams distribution?

Comment: Those are added "on demand". It did not come up yet. Feel free to file a ticket about it (or even contribute an implementation -- this would require a KIP though). Happy to support you on it. (Yes, it's not totally simply so it might be a good value add to have an implementation that ships with Kafka out-of-the-box.)